# Rename variable using categorical data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was wondering how to rename observations in a pandas dataframe with more columns,
for example:

```
User Age Value Smoke? ....
21   18   0.5    1
212  30   0.2    1
211  32   0.7    0
214  64   0.2    1
212  30   0.2    1
```

For one column I found that this code

```
pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=[-np.inf, 30, np.inf], labels=['<30', '>=30'])
```

should work fine.
But I'd like to know how to rename ages in categorical variable (`<30` and `>=30`), in the dataframe above, having more columns, dropping duplicate values.

Output would be

```
User Age Value Smoke? ....
21   <30   0.5    1
212  >=30   0.2    1
211  >=30   0.7    0
214  >=30   0.2    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try assigning the age column to the pd.cut? like this:

```
df['Age'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=[-np.inf, 30, np.inf], labels=['<30', '>=30'])
```

then to drop duplicate rows you can simply use this:

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```